# Issue regarding SSAS features while trying to process a cube in BIDS

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, bids

I recently adventured into BI and am currently trying to process a cube onto the ssas (by using a BIDS SASS project). I originally had the SQL 20008 R2 Standard version and therefore got the following error:

[image: Error that i get whenever i try to process the cube]

"Errors related to feature availability and configuration: The 'Perspectives' feature is not included in the '64 Bit Standard' edition of Analysis Services"

So...i downloaded the Enterprise version of SQL 2008 R2, upgraded my whole instance, restarted and proceeded to try again. STILL i got the same issue over again...

What could i do to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The issues with Enterprise version.Use the Standard version.
Keep one thing in your mind give sysadmin permissions to NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the SQL SERVER ,SQL SERVER ANALYSIS SERVICES from Services.msc . I got it resolved the same issue by doing this.